# Java how to sort multimap vs?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, multimap

I use Guava multimap to store data from a textfile.
The textfile data format is like:

```
p1 10
p2 30
p3 40
p1 20
p2 50
p3 60
..
..
```

First column is the key and second is the value. I want to sort the score(value) from highest to lowest, but have no idea how to sort a multimap..
or is there a better storage to store that kind of data?

What other thing I thought is making two arraylist, one for name and another for scores, though

I don't know it is possible to link two lists.

```
list1 = {p1,p2,p3}
list2 = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60}
```

p1 index directing 10 and 20. Is this kind of thing possible?

Comment: SortedMap< String, SortedSet< String >> map = new TreeMap<>(); If you want more tell me...

Comment: See [Having a Multimap sorted on keys only in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501468/having-a-multimap-sorted-on-keys-only-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:-

```
 public static ImmutableMultimap<Integer, MyObject> indexOnScore(Iterable<MyObject> i) {
  List<MyObject> sorted = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(myObjectToScore())
  .sortedCopy(i);
   return Multimaps.index(sorted, myObjectToScore());
}
```

Another option might be to create a `TreeMultimap` and use `Ordering.arbitrary()` as the Comparator for the values.