# Sorting the data in increasing order based on keys in Multimap Google Guava

Tags: java, key, guava, multimap

I created a Multimap

```
Multimap<Integer, String> mhm= ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

my numbers range from 0 to 2400.

I have inserted data like

```
 mhm.put(800 ,"A")
 mhm.put(1200 ,"B")
 mhm.put(1200 ,"A")
 mhm.put(1500 ,"B")
 mhm.put(600 ,"A")
 mhm.put(700 ,"B")
 mhm.put(1200 ,"A")
 mhm.put(1201 ,"B")
```

I want to sort the Multimap on key field that is Integer? There are not much posts on satckoverflow which tells how to do this.

expected output:

```
 mhm.put(600 ,"A")
 mhm.put(700 ,"B")
 mhm.put(800 ,"A")
 mhm.put(1200 ,"B")
 mhm.put(1200 ,"A")
 mhm.put(1200 ,"A")
 mhm.put(1201 ,"A")
 mhm.put(1500 ,"B")
```

Please note that the expected output is sorted only on key. 
**If two keys have same value then the key which appeared first should come first**. 
how to enforce this? Is this case automatically taken care when we sort the Multimap on keys?

*This is not homework question, trying to play around Google Guava.*

Comment: You conform its not homework

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501468/having-a-multimap-sorted-on-keys-only-in-java

Comment: @S.SWAIN I just finished my semester exams. trying to prepare for placements. I am not that good at java.  I need some help in solving it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want keys in natural order - just use custom `Multimap` using [`newListMultimap` from `Multimaps` class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v15.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#newListMultimap%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Supplier%29):

```
ListMultimap<Integer, String> mhm = Multimaps.newListMultimap(
  new TreeMap<Integer, Collection<String>>(),
  new Supplier<List<String>>() {
    public List<String> get() {
      return Lists.newArrayList();
    }
  });
```

In Java 8 it's shorter:

```
ListMultimap<Integer, String> mhm = Multimaps.newListMultimap(
    new TreeMap<>(), ArrayList::new);
```

But if you're using Guava 16+ (and you should now), you can use [`MultimapBuilder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MultimapBuilder.html) which is even more clean:

```
ListMultimap<Integer, String> mhm = MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build();
```

Because you can think of multimap as map key -> collection, just use JDK's [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) which is *sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys*.

Example:

```
mhm.put(2, "some");
mhm.put(1, "value");
mhm.put(2, "here");
System.out.println(mhm.toString());
// { 1: [ "value" ], 2: [ "some", "here" ] }
```

Comment: I want them to be sorted in first place but if there are duplicate keys, then natural order should be maintained

Comment: It's Multimap, so if there are entries with duplicate keys put in the multimap, they'll be added to corresponding value collection (here: `List`).

Comment: Thanks @Xaerxess for suggesting the MultimapBuilder

Answer (score 5):

If you can use an immutable multimap, and don't need to mutate the multimap, then it's fairly simple:

```
new ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<Integer, String>
   .orderKeysBy(Ordering.natural())
   .putAll(multimap) // or put each entry
   .build();
```