# LinkedHashMap or Multimap

Tags: java, multimap, linkedhashmap

```
LinkedHashMap<String, List<Object>>  = ???

linkedHashMap.put("a", list1);
linkedHashMap.put("e, list2);
linkedHashMap.put("i", list3);
linkedHashMap.put("o", list4);
linkedHashMap.put("u", list5);
linkedHashMap.put("g", list6);
linkedHashMap.put("a", list7);
```

I want to receive exactly in same order and I can have duplicate keys.

Comment: Maps can never have duplicate keys

Comment: `MultiMap` in favor of reuse. 
http://www.baeldung.com/guava-multimap

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501468/having-a-multimap-sorted-on-keys-only-in-java/24674964

Comment: classic multimap is a map where value is a collection of value, in your case you may look for LinkedHashMap<String, Collection<List<Object>>>

Comment: I'm sorry, I could have told this before but I'm not using any Guava. Is it third party Jar?

Comment: @cricket_007 you are right. But my scenario is different even i have duplicates I want my map in same order.

Comment: Again, Maps simply cannot have duplicate keys. Explain how you would get data **out** of this, not just putting data in it... For example, what are you expecting as output?

Comment: Just out of curiousity i wanted to know what are you expecting as output? LinkedHashMap preserves the order of insertion but doesn't allow duplicate key. Do you mean even if we allow duplicates then the list of objects held by them should be different? Will storing the objects in the list for a given key i.e as per your example if you get "a" as a key can't u update the list1?

Comment: @cricket_007 Right now my out put is: {a=[list1, list7], e=[list2], i=[list3],o=[list4],u=[list5],g=[list6]}.

Comment: @cricket_007 So its printing as: a,a,e,i,o,u,g  but i'm expecting as a,e,i,o,u,g,a

Comment: What is printing? There is no print code in the question. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: What is the actual question here? Which class to use? If you want duplicate keys you can't use `LinkedHashMap`, unless you make it a map of lists.

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry for confusing you. when i say printing, I mean output.

Comment: @Nain guava is 3rd library  lib: https://github.com/google/guava, it does not make sense to reinvent the wheel, LinkedListMultimap give you all that you have asked

Comment: I know what output and print mean... It is unclear what part of the code provided is resulting in that output. Please edit your question to show us what you actually want and the code you've tried to get to that result.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you were to preserve exactly the same order for entries, you can use LinkedListMultimap entries() method:, see also how it differs from get method.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Object> list1 = Arrays.asList(1);
    List<Object> list2 = Arrays.asList(2);
    List<Object> list3 = Arrays.asList(3);
    List<Object> list4 = Arrays.asList(4);
    List<Object> list5 = Arrays.asList(5);
    List<Object> list6 = Arrays.asList(6);
    List<Object> list7 = Arrays.asList(7);

    Multimap<String, List<Object>> mmap = LinkedListMultimap.create();
    mmap.put("a", list1);
    mmap.put("e", list2);
    mmap.put("i", list3);
    mmap.put("o", list4);
    mmap.put("u", list5);
    mmap.put("g", list6);
    mmap.put("a", list7);


    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Object>> entry : mmap.entries()) {
      System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    }

    System.out.println("Multimap key grouped  values");

    for (String key : mmap.keys()) {
      System.out.println(key+ " " + mmap.get(key));
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: do I need GUAVA library to implement LinkedListMultimap ?

Comment: you would need GUAVA library to use com.google.common.collect.LinkedListMultimap and  com.google.common.collect.Multimap, updated import for provided solution

Comment: Thanku @Witas, but I don't want to use GUAVA library. Can we do without using GUAVA library?

Comment: in that case you would  write simple multimap implementation, http://www.techiedelight.com/implement-multimap-java/